# wp_editor shows no button

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

I'm trying to use wp_editor in a simple PHP page (not a plugin, not in the admin section) :

```
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('wp-blog-header.php');
  $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
  wp_editor( "My content", $editor_id );
```

I got the field and the Visual/HTML buttons but that's all, I don't have any other buttons or toolbar.

Do I need to load other WP library before calling wp_editor ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some settings variable to editor as well. Without passing it, it will take default values.

Another thing I have noticed that, If I do `exit();` anywhere in my page before loading footer, it will not display any buttons in toolbar as it loads some of the scripts from footer. So If you have `exit()` or `die()` before loading footer it will not load the toolbar.

Here I have passed it to my editor and its working fine.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
$settings =   array(
    'wpautop' => true, // use wpautop?
    'media_buttons' => true, // show insert/upload button(s)
    'textarea_name' => $editor_id, // set the textarea name to something different, square brackets [] can be used here
    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), // rows="..."
    'tabindex' => '',
    'editor_css' => '', //  extra styles for both visual and HTML editors buttons, 
    'editor_class' => '', // add extra class(es) to the editor textarea
    'teeny' => false, // output the minimal editor config used in Press This
    'dfw' => false, // replace the default fullscreen with DFW (supported on the front-end in WordPress 3.4)
    'tinymce' => true, // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()

    'quicktags' => true // load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
);
 wp_editor( "My content", $editor_id, $settings );
```